# Replace product link with just product name on WooCommerce downloads page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

In WooCommerce when we go to "Downloads" section, list of downloads is displayed which contain product name(linked to the product) and link to download the file.

Is there a way to remove the link of product and just display product name?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the product link from the product name on MY Account Downloads

```
// Display the product name without the link 
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'custom_account_downloads_product_column' );
function custom_account_downloads_product_column( $download ){
    // Display the product name without the link
    echo esc_html( $download['product_name'] );
}
```